# virt-viewer not starting up correctly

Tags: rhel7, virt-manager

I just installed virt-viewer on RHEL7.3 using **yum install virt-viewer** and now I am getting below error

```
[root@host ~]# virt-viewer 
virt-viewer: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libspice-client-gtk-3.0.so.5: undefined symbol: gdk_keymap_get_scroll_lock_state
```

virt-manager also crashes when I try to see graphical console.

[image]

Target library seems to exist so something is wrong with the dependency.

```
[root@host ~]# ls -l /lib64/libspice*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      33 Aug 12 15:56 /lib64/libspice-client-glib-2.0.so -> libspice-client-glib-2.0.so.8.6.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      33 Aug 12 15:06 /lib64/libspice-client-glib-2.0.so.8 -> libspice-client-glib-2.0.so.8.6.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1200664 Jun  8 00:49 /lib64/libspice-client-glib-2.0.so.8.6.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      32 Aug 12 16:08 /lib64/libspice-client-gtk-3.0.so.5 -> libspice-client-gtk-3.0.so.5.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  132176 Jun  8 00:49 /lib64/libspice-client-gtk-3.0.so.5.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      28 Aug 12 15:56 /lib64/libspice-controller.so -> libspice-controller.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      28 Aug 12 15:07 /lib64/libspice-controller.so.0 -> libspice-controller.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   69096 Jun  8 00:49 /lib64/libspice-controller.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      24 Dec 25  2016 /lib64/libspice-server.so.1 -> libspice-server.so.1.8.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1194648 Sep  9  2016 /lib64/libspice-server.so.1.8.0
```

Is there anyone else faced the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem.

## Problem

When I install virt-viewer from yum repository, 1 package is installed and 2 packages are updated.

```
Installing:
 virt-viewer                       x86_64                       5.0-7.el7                         rhel-7-server-rpms                       389 k
Updating for dependencies:
 spice-glib                        x86_64                       0.33-6.el7                        rhel-7-server-rpms                       376 k
 spice-gtk3                        x86_64                       0.33-6.el7                        rhel-7-server-rpms                        83 k
```

As a result, below error occurs.

```
[root@host ~]# virt-viewer -h
virt-viewer: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libspice-client-gtk-3.0.so.5: undefined symbol: gdk_keymap_get_scroll_lock_state
```

Looks like latest *spice-glib* and *spice-gtk3* is not working properly with *virt-viewer* .

## Work Around

Install the *virt-viewer* from the *rhel-server-7.3-x86_64-dvd.iso* . spice related packages are not updated and virt-viewer properly works now.

```
Installing:
 virt-viewer                           x86_64                           2.0-12.el7                           dvd                           344 k
```

It works properly now.

```
[root@host ~]# virt-viewer --version
virt-viewer version 2.0-12.el7
```

Compatible  *spice-glib* and *spice-gtk3* are below.

```
  Installing : spice-glib-0.31-6.el7.x86_64                                                                                                  1/5 
  Installing : spice-gtk3-0.31-6.el7.x86_64                                                                                                  2/5 
  Installing : virt-manager-common-1.4.0-2.el7.noarch                                                                                        3/5 
  Installing : virt-manager-1.4.0-2.el7.noarch                                                                                               4/5 
  Installing : virt-viewer-2.0-12.el7.x86_64                                                                                                 5/5
```